# Finding the opposite of a number in a 0 to 10 scale

Tags: math

This is probably something silly and simple in vectors or something, but I can't figure it out with my remedial Algebra. (Sorry for the initial confusion, I didn't fully explain this as I didn't think the 2nd half of my operation was relevant.)

I have a variable between 0 and 10. I want to find its opposite in that same scale, but I also want to change the "depth" of what that opposite means.

Variables:
    X = User input variable between 0-10 (really 0-1.0)
    Y = User input Depth between 0-10 (really 0-1.0)
    Z = My result I'm looking for.

Example if my depth (Y) is Full (10), X would be:
    X=0's opposite would be 10
    X=1's opposite would be 9
    X=2's opposite would be 8
etc..

Example if my depth (Y) is None (0), X would be:
    X=0's opposite would be 0
    X=1's opposite would be 1
    X=2's opposite would be 2
etc..

I'm trying to accomplish this in Reaktor, a program for designing musical synthesizers. Specifically designing a "depth" parameter on a Chorus effect that inverts the left and right signal delay. So that the "rate" (X in this example) for the left signal is the opposite of the "rate" for the right signal, and the difference of how opposite they are is controlled by the "depth" (Y).

Comment: vectors are not necessary, this *is* simple algebra

Comment: Sorry, I should have gone into greater depth on what I was trying to accomplish. I have edited the post to reflect the entirety of what I am trying to do here.

Comment: In the question, you say if Depth is 10, then X's opposite is `(10-X)`. If Depth is 0, then X's opposite is `X`. What would X's opposite be if the Depth is 5?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `x` is your number, then what you're looking for is simply `(10 - x)`.

**edit** One functional form that satisfies your updated spec is `(x + y - (x * y) / 5.0)`. This is designed for values of `x` and `y` between `0` and `10`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have gone into greater depth on what I was trying to accomplish. I have edited the post to reflect the entirety of what I am trying to do here.

Comment: I am getting wild results with this. Fortunately Reaktor shows its math! With the / 5.0 I get garbage (X = 5 and Y = 10 I get -7!?), but if I look at the calculation just before that when it is subtracting x * y from x + y I get ALMOST the right answer. The second digit of everything it spits out is the correct answer, and the first digit is wrong. X = 4, Y = 10 and I get -26. (The 6 is correct!) X = 4, Y = 5 I get -11 (The 1 is correct, 2 would be more correct, but I'm not that picky).  X = 3, Y = 10 and I get -17 (7 is correct). X = 3, Y = 4 and I get 5 (which is kind of off, but close!).

Comment: @user980680: The results clearly disagree with the formula I have suggested. I know nothing about Reaktor, so can only suggest that you double-check the formula in Reaktor and put parentheses everywhere to ensure the order of evaluation is as it should be: `(x + y - ((x * y) / 5.0))`.

Comment: Ohhh.. I was doing it (x +y - (x * y)) / 5.0! That way works! I tried it with every combination I can think of and it gave me the right answer... except for when Y is 5. When Y is 5, every answer = 5. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me out on this. I know it can't be easy trying to help a total stranger understand math.

Answer (score 1):

X = 10 - Y where Y is input and X is output

0's opposite is 10: 10 = 10-0
1's opposite is 9: 9 = 10-1
2's opposite is 8: 8 = 10-2